# Power supply for off-grid

Tags: batteries

I live off grid. My question is this. I run off a 3000 watt generator and my next step is this. Run a generator to a battery bank charger overcharge protected. Then to 10 deep cycle AGM 12 volt batteries, then to a 5000 watt 12 volt inverter and from there to my cabin. Will this work to save on fuel or should I look for a better plan? any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: It mainly comes down to the overall efficiency of converting the energy in the fuel, through the engine, generator, battery charger, batteries and inverter.  The efficiency of operating a mains-voltage AC generator into an ordinary mains-rated charger could probably be improved. But perhaps the convenience of having a mains-voltage generator as an alternate source outweighs the loss of efficency. There are really a great many details in play we don't know about here. And many alternative solutions. Not a quick-n-easy answer.

Comment: I think you need to really study up on battery systems. You definitely do not want to buy any 5000W 12 V inverter because it would require around 500 Amps at 12V to deliver 5000W. Sizing of the battery bank is also very important. You can't charge/discharge lead acid batteries at rates approaching 1C. You probably want to keep it at around 0.25C or less for battery longevity. Even so, you will have to de-rate the battery capacity. I think the basic idea is OK, but you need to keep reading about the topic.

Comment: Draw a schematic of your setup!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it depends on your load rather than the size of your generator.
Typically if you divide your generator full load gallons/hr by 3 you get your quarter power fuel consumption. Below quarter load on the generator the fuel wastage (just to keep the generator turning, and produce lots of unused heat) ratio increases for all engine driven generators.

So if your cabin consumes 3000/4 = 750 W or less then you are typically wasting more fuel (the percentage varies with generator speed, rotating mass etc). Obviously as you approach no load (say 100 W or so), virtually all the fuel you consume is a waste.

If you implement a battery/inverter solution and you run at say 750 W or less, then you will definitely save fuel. And if you run close to no load (say 100 W or so) on the invertor you will save significant fuel.
You should ensure that you get the largest possible charger for your battery pack, so that when the generator does run, it charges the batteries in the smallest time and highest load possible (most fuel efficient).

You might consider also that the equation for generator design has changed in recent years. Some manufacturers now produce generators with DC-AC invertors inside them. These generators can slow down when lightly loaded and speed up as the load increases. This significantly reduces the waste fuel so might also be a potential solution for you.